# Symfony assets in web folder not found by apache

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I copied my symfony2 project to shared hosting.

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /web
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Now  page is loading but no assets(js,css files) are loaded. When I try to open them `myhost/assets/css/style.css`  I receive an error:

```
ops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

All assets located in web/assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Check apache config, or add to `.htaccess` uncommented last line from this doc:

```
# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks
```